# How to make an SVG scale without viewbox attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

I'm trying to scale a ReactJS component such that it expands to fit its parent div container. The component returns an

```
<svg/>
```

element with several children. The API of the react component only lets me set the svg element's CSS style. I don't have a way to give the svg element a viewbox attribute.

Is there a way for me to get the SVG to scale to fill its parent container through CSS only?

The react component for reference: [link](https://michaellyons.github.io/react-launch-gauge/)

Comment: Not easily, that's the reason the viewBox attribute exists.

Comment: Doesn't `someSelector svg {display:block; width: 100%}` work?

Comment: No, it expands the svg to fill the entire area, but it does not scale the children of the svg. Meaning, the items drawn stay where they are and don't scale

Comment: If the SVG has width and height properties set then as far as I know you're out of luck.

Comment: Well, you might be able to hack your way around it by traversing the DOM after the SVG is mounted and set a `viewBox` property via vanilla JavaScript but that's probably not going to be a very good solution in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Well, quite simple. All you need to do is combine [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) and [transform: scale()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale). This solution was applied to stretch the svg world map into the area of dashboard widget on the prod build of app in the company where I work.

[image: screenshot]

There is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/tripolskypetr/29b1263bfa29075411c66c088144d1ce) which published with a link to JSFiddle demo.

```
(function() {

  const parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
  const item = document.querySelector('.item');
  let scaleAdjust = 1.0;
    
  const process = (container, ref) => {
    const {
      height: originHeight,
      width: originWidth
     } = ref.getBoundingClientRect();
    const {
      height: containerHeight,
      width: containerWidth,
    } = container.getBoundingClientRect();
    const [height, width] = [originHeight * scaleAdjust, originWidth * scaleAdjust];
    const [from, to] = height > width ? [width, containerWidth] : [height, containerHeight];
    const scale = to / from;
    ref.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;
    scaleAdjust = 1 / scale;
  };

  new ResizeObserver(() => process(parent, item)).observe(document.body);
    
})();
```